# Select text in TextView on simple click or programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I just want to select text in `TextView` like with long press but with simple touch (click).

Or select some text in `TextView` programmatically (It's easy to get the clicked position in `TextView`).

Comment: Read this: https://medium.com/google-developers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999

Comment: I already saw it but not resolve the issue. Select is always on long click

Comment: Do you need to select all the text or just a desired part of it?

Comment: just a part of the text